# 80's/90's superhero cartoon with a man on fire and a man who made ice runways like Frozone

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember a cartoon I watched as a child either in the late 80's or very early 90's. It had superheroes in it including a man made of fire who could fly and a man made of ice who traveled everywhere by making an ice runway that he slid along, much like Frozone in *The Incredibles*.

Am pretty sure it was a series.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Frozone's method of transportation was directly copied from Iceman.

Comment: I'm reminded of the comicbook *Marvel Team-Up*, which consisted of one-shot stories featuring two established superheroes. Most issues had Spider-Man as one of the pair, but Iceman (from the original X-Men) and the Human Torch (from the Fantastic Four) were paired more than once.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### [*Spider-Man and His Amazing Friends*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083481/) (1981 - 1986)

> In this series, Spider-Man forms a close friendship and alliance with two superheroes, Iceman and Firestar. Together, the group, informally known as "The Spider Friends", battle crime in New York City. Along the way, they not only face Spider-Man's own enemies, but also other major Marvel Comics villians like the Red Skull and Doctor Doom while also meeting other heroes of the Marvel Universe.

The two superheroes are Iceman and Firestar.

[image: Gif showing Iceman spraying ice on the ground and sliding along on it]

[image: Gif showing Firestar going "on fire" and flying away]

As was mentioned in the comments there was one episode where we see Sunfire, a male superhero with similar powers to Firestar so that might be why you are thinking it was a man.

Comment: It's probably obvious from the image, but might be worth starting Firestar was actually female (although replacing a male character from the comics the production wanted to use)

Comment: There was one episode with "Sunfire", whom was a male with powers similar to Firestar.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - Indeed there was; https://youtu.be/6zFuK0C6q5c?t=83